# Keyboard Backlight not Working on Arch Linux

Tags: linux, laptop, keyboard, arch-linux, backlight

I've recently bought an HP Pavilion laptop, sent evil Windows to hell and installed Arch Linux. After several hours of work, everything's fine - except the keyboard backlight. The backlight and the little LED indicating muted sound don't work.
Does some neckbeard of you got an idea what the problem could be?

It's not really hindering but my pride tells me to get this thing working.

EDIT:
Found https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keyboard_backlight. Following the instructions gave me the following error:

```
~/Test >>> python3 kb-light.py + 1                                                                                  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "kb-light.py", line 26, in <module>
    print(kb_light_set(int(sys.argv[2])))
  File "kb-light.py", line 11, in kb_light_set
    current = kbd_backlight.GetBrightness()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 70, in __call__
    return self._proxy_method(*args, **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 145, in __call__
    **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such interface “org.freedesktop.UPower.KbdBacklight” on object at path /org/freedesktop/UPower/KbdBacklight
```

Updating *upower* as suggested [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=240392) didn't help. Using *xset* as discussed [here](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/keyboard-back-light-keeps-turning-off/22500) works neither.
The only [up-to-date thread](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/62426) from April consists of a sad guy having the exact same problem as me; without any replies.

Comment: It smells like driver compatibility. Did you try other distro Debian, Ubuntu, Manjaro etc.?

Comment: @Biswapriyo Haven't tried; I'll tell when I'm done

Comment: Doesn't work with newest Ubuntu either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a script to fix issue I had with this:

```
#! /bin/bash


if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
    echo "Usage: bash $0 <on|off>"
    echo "       alternatively bash $0 <1|0> can be used as well"
else
    if [[ $1 == 'on' ]] || [[ $1 == '1' ]]
    then
        sudo tee /sys/class/leds/tpacpi\:\:kbd_backlight/brightness <<< 3
    elif [[ $1 == 'off' ]] || [[ $1 == '0' ]]
    then
        sudo tee /sys/class/leds/tpacpi\:\:kbd_backlight/brightness <<< 0
    else
        echo "Usage: bash $0 on|off"
    fi
fi
```

Comment: For some laptops the folder for the **tpacpi** part will be a little different. See what shows up for you in that /sys/class/leds directory

Comment: regarding your sound issue, try to mute/unmute your sound by doing: `amixer set Master toggle`